# Can MySQL use roles without MySQL Wokbench?

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have only found documentation about roles in MySQL through the use of Workbench, is there an alternative way to set them?

Answer (score 0):

No.  MySQL does not support roles (not even in 5.5).  MySQL Workbench doesn't create roles as such but provides a role like interface to the model - the underlying code isn't creating roles but making direct grants to users.